# Can not start the Azure Storage Emulator

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, azure-storage-emulator

I am creating my first azure function on VS 2019. When I try to run, it comes with this error:

[image: error message image]

I am using OS win 10. And the version of my VS is 16.4.29728.190. What kind of role does the Storage Emulator play in the azure function? Why am I encountering this problem, is it that I haven't configured the azure function? How to fix it?

Comment: There may be a problem with the storage component.

Comment: @BowmanZhu I can not start AzureStorageEmulator, so how to fix it?

Comment: I suggest that you to open VS installer, please remove the storage related components, and then reinstall, it may take tens of minutes.

Comment: What about run the emulator manually?

Comment: @BowmanZhu Yes, you are right. After reinstall the components in VS, I can run the function now.

Comment: I have post my answer. If my solution helps, can you [mark it](https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/work/mark.png) as the answer of this question? This may help others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:**

Updating the answer, I found that the more common situation is port occupation. If you encounter this problem, you can query the usage of port 10000 and then kill the process occupying the port.

First, search:

```
netstat -p tcp -ano | findstr :10000
```

Then, kill:

```
taskkill /T /F /PID yourPID
```

There is also a rare case in which you can avoid the problem by simply crossing off the error window.

**Original Answer:**

The problem you encountered is accidental. It has nothing to do with the function configuration. The problem is that the related component has a problem. Reinstalling it can solve the problem.

It ’s not a difficult issue to troubleshoot, it ’s just a bit frustrating that it happens in the first place.

1, Obviously, you first need to ensure that the Azure Storage Emulator is installed on your machine. This is part of the Azure SDK, so you should be OK if you've installed that. However, you can install the emulator as a stand -alone app. To check if it is installed on your machine, click on Windows Start and type “Azure Storage Emulator”.

2, If the application is displayed in your Start menu, you can go ahead and run it manually. This will invoke a console window that will inform you of the emulator being ready to be used.

3.If the application is not displayed in your Start menu, either install the full Azure SDK or the stand-alone Azure Storage Emulator app, as explained earlier.

4, For more information, navigate to Microsoft ’s docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator).

Comment: I see the same problem, there is a processing using port 10000 and I've killed it to work normally

Answer (score 2):

There was no process occupying the port '10000' in my case. Found a solution in the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/933) and modifying the port to '20000' (see img) in the config file at path ***C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config*** worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting this along with VS 2019 debugger, you have to start VS 2019 in Administrator mode. Otherwise first start the storage emulator separately before starting debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Cindy helped to some extent, I my case I had to create database manually as was getting error message on database creation failed when I was starting storage Emulator manually from start menu.

Once database was created, storage emulator started smoothly and there was no need to start emulator manually before running the function from VS 2019.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).